# VBA Excel - reference variably named worksheets for chart series

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that runs over a series of files. It creates a second worksheet in a given workbook, and then gets the data from the first worksheet in that workbook. This worked well when the first worksheet in every file was named "Fall". Now, however, the first worksheet in each file has a different name for each workbook.

I need to create the second worksheet and then get the data from the first worksheet in each file without explicitly using the worksheet's name. One line in the previous code looked like this:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Fall!$A$2:$A$2"
```

This gave me the data series name on the chart. But now the WS name is NOT "Fall". It changes from file to file. It is also the name of the file itself, if that helps.

I just need to reference the *previous* WS -not the "active" sheet where the chart is being built- and I don't know what to call it. I have tried:

```
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='" & Sheetname.Name & "' & !$A$2:$A$2"
```

This is choosing the correct cell and when I **hover** over the code in Debug, *the correct name is showing up*, but when I run the code I get "Runtime error '1004: Parameter not valid" and it won't continue to run. That is the line giving me trouble.

I tried countless variations - removing the single quote, adding quotes, removing ampersands, changing to `Sheet1.name` rather than `Sheetname.Name`, changing to `Sheet(1)`, or `Worksheet(1)`. I tried recording a macro, but that gave me the specific reference to the page in that particular file, so it didn't help. I also tried changing the file from a `.csv` to a `.xlsm`; didn't help.

I tried changing `!$A$2:$A$2` to just `!$A$2`. I don't know what the problem is. I feel like it is probably something simple.

This is my sample of code:

```
Sub Graph_NEW()
' This is the macro that will graph a "Historic" line (flat mean) with the projected data for ea HUC8.
' Graphs columns B & C then adds G, to a second worksheet

    Dim Sheetname As Worksheet
    Set Sheetname = Worksheets(1)
        
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='" & Sheetname.Name & "'!$A$2:$A$2"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "'" & Sheetname.Name & "'!$C$2:$C$140"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "'" & Sheetname.Name & "'!$B$2:$B$140"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Historic Mean"""
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & Sheetname.Name & "' & "!$F$2:$F$140"

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1) = Sheets("Fall").Cells(2, 1).Value

    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "YEAR"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "YEAR"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 4).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
```

I have also highlighted line 9 of the code because this line is formatted differently and I need help to know how I'd have to adjust it as well. Currently it's the old code.

This is a small sample of one `.csv` file:

```
HUC8    YEAR    RO_MM   HIST    HUC Historic Mean
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1961    62.4    HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1962    107.6   HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1963    140.1   HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1964    172.3   HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1965    138.5   HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1966    147     HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1967    105.1   HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1968    62.6    HistFall    1010001 141.7455    
mricgcm3_45Fall_1010001 1969    170.1   HistFall    1010001 141.7455
```

Also, I have asked this question elsewhere. I don't know why that is frowned upon in some places, I'm just trying to get help. It was not answered anywhere, but I wanted to be upfront about that. Thanks guys.

Comment: Try `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & Sheetname.Name & "!$A$2"`?

Comment: Nope. Got the same "Run-time error '1004': Parameter not valid". I've tried it on .csv, .xlsx, .xlsm files and also checked the Trust Center properties as suggested online. No change.

Comment: You forgot to add a new series, Add `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` before `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & Sheetname.Name & "!$A$2"`, with your current code, `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count` is 0 so there's no collection to assign the name in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Raymond! Please put it in an answer so that I can give you credit. It is very weird to me that this was the problem because this same code ran before and I didn't have to do that for the last series. ALSO - would you be able to tell me how I would have to change line 9? Currently `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1) = Sheetname.Cells(2, 1).Value`. But that's not working.

Comment: I'm not familiar with chart and stuffs actually so I'm not exactly sure what is line 9 supposed to do. `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)` is a `Series` object so I don't think you can assign a value from `A2` into it. What is `A2` value and what should it be in the series?

Comment: That line labels the gets the label for the data series actually, while the first line creates the title. The way it worked before is exactly what I have in the OP when the WS was named "Fall". And again, I just need it to choose that cell to label the data in the graph. When I use `Sheetname.Cells(2,1).Value`, I get Runtime Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. But as I say, it worked perfectly when it was `Sheets("Fall").Cells(2, 1).Value`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your clarification, would you be able to give an example based on the sample csv in your question? A screenshot of the expected outcome would be the best if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You did not add a new series so there is 0 `Series` object in the collection for you to change the name. So you need to add a Series before you can modify its property.
2. Since you are referencing only 1 cell, you can trim it to:

```
"='" & Sheetname.Name & "'!$A$2"
```

3. It is highly recommended to avoid the use of `Select`/`Activate`, `ActiveSheet` and other similar reference as it is not reliable (it can break when you change the focus of the workbook/worksheet while the code is running).

Please read [this on how to avoid using Select/Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

Taking above into account, try this snippet and modify it to your full code:

```
Sub Graph_NEW()
' This is the macro that will graph a "Historic" line (flat mean) with the projected data for ea HUC8.
' Graphs columns B & C then adds G, to a second worksheet

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    
    
    Set newSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=dataSheet)
    
    Dim newChart As Chart
    Set newChart = newSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Chart
    
    With newChart
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "='" & dataSheet.Name & "'!$A$2"
            .Values = "='" & dataSheet.Name & "'!$C$2:$C$140"
            .XValues = "='" & dataSheet.Name & "'!$B$2:$B$140"
        End With
        
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "Historic Mean"
            .Values = "='" & dataSheet.Name & "'!$F$2:$F$140"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're right. I found another version and the `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count` was there. I had lost it somehow in trying to revise it. As for the rest, I will use what you have provided -much appreciated. I was never taught VBA, and cobble together things I find online, like many people. Unfortunately one never knows what is current protocol when grabbing from multiple places, often many years old, and with a project that needs to get finished. And most code offered -while gratefully received- is without an explanation of how or why. Doing my best. Thanks.

Comment: The link is helpful.

Comment: @DavidMontana Good to know it helps, most of the time you can discover these problems by stepping through the code and debug the issue at the point of error. If you have not been doing so then its helpful to go read up on how to debug codes.

Comment: In general, you may need the single quotes around the sheet name. If you add them unnecessarily, Excel/VBA strips them without a complaint.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this! It certainly did not occur to me that it could be necessarily depending on the worksheet name. I have edited my answer to reflect this point. @JonPeltier